# Video conversion with ffmpeg to target Android and iOS mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, node.js, video, ffmpeg

I'm building a react native app for both Android and IOS, the back-end API is written with NodeJS.

Users may upload video from their phones, once uploaded the user and their friends will be able to view the video - so the videos need to be stored in a format which is playable on both Android & IOS.

My question relates to the conversion of video, uploaded by the user. I developed a similar app a couple of years ago; I used the repo [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) which provides a nice API to interact with FFmpeg.

In the previous project (which was a web app), I converted the uploaded videos into two files, one .mp4 and one .webm - if a user uploaded an mp4, then I would skip the mp4 step, likewise if they uploaded a .webm.

This was kind of slow. Now I've come across the same requirement years later, after some research I think I was wrong to convert the videos to the last project.

I've read that I can simply use FFmpeg to change the container format of the videos, which is a much faster process than converting them from scratch.

The video conversion code I used last time went something along the lines of:

```
var convertVideo = function (source, format, output, success, failure, progress) {

    var converter = ffmpeg(source);

    var audioCodec = "libvorbis";

    if (format.indexOf("mp4") != -1) {
        audioCodec = "aac";
    }

    converter.format(format)
        .withVideoBitrate(1024)
        .withAudioCodec(audioCodec)
        .on('end', success)
        .on('progress', progress)
        .on('error', failure);

    converter.save(output);
};
```

Usage:

Convert to mp4:

```
convertVideo("PATH_TO_VIDEO", "mp4", "foo.mp4", () => {console.log("success");});
```

Convert to webm:

```
convertVideo("PATH_TO_VIDEO", "webm", "foo.webm", () => {console.log("success");});
```

Can anyone point out a code smell here regarding the performance of this operation? Is this code doing a lot more than it should achieve cross-platform compatibility between IOS and Android?

Might be worth mentioning that support for older OS versions is not such a big deal in this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is the difference between codec and container/format?**

You should [understand the difference](https://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp) between a codec (e.g. H.264, VP9) and a container format (e.g. MP4, WebM). The container just stores the encoded video and audio information. Usually, you can change between containers by streamcopying (`ffmpeg -i input -c copy output`), but for historic reasons, you'll find that some containers don't accept some codecs, or that some players may not handle a codec within a container (e.g. only recent software will be able to read VP9 video in MP4). Have a look at [this overview of container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) to see which codecs are supported.

**What are the constraints imposed by different mobile OSes?**

For targeting iOS and Android platforms, you then need to check if a given video file is compatible with the supported codecs / formats:

- [Android supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#video-formats)
- [iOS supported media formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) and also the description at the bottom of the [iPhone specification page](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

Thee may change over time, of course, but generally, the common denominator is:

- H.264 video
- MP4 container
- Main profile
- A maximum resolution of 1920×1080 – although the resolution could be higher if the device supports it, but there's rarely a need to go above Full HD for mobile devices, since people cannot perceive the difference between that and 4K/UHD unless it's a big tablet.
- The frame rate should not exceed a certain maximum (e.g. 60 Hz)
- The chroma subsampling should be 4:2:0.
- AAC-LC audio

The specific constraints depend on the device, obviously, and the operating system version installed. Not all of these specifics are mentioned in the iOS/Android documentation. You should definitely do a few trials, and, if unsure, re-encode the video.

**So, what codec/format should I encode with?**

Apple has invested a lot in the MPEG ecosystem and traditionally has better support for H.264 and H.265 (HEVC); they don't support VP8 and VP9 in WebM. Thus, if you have a VP8/VP9 video, and you want it to be viewable cross-platform, re-encode it to H.264.

**How should I do the actual encoding?**

Make sure you use a high enough bitrate to not add further artifacts to already lossy video. You should *not* just do a one-pass target bitrate encode as you're doing now. Instead, do two-pass encoding to increase the quality and efficiency of the encode (although it takes longer). You can also use a constant quality mode if you do not care about a particular file size (such as [CRF for libx264](http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html)). Read the [FFmpeg H.264 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

**What about the future?**

Note that almost all the big players in the tech industry—except Apple—have joined the [Alliance for Open Media](http://aomedia.org/). They're developing the successor to VP9, called “[AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOMedia_Video_1)”, which will gain support in all major browser vendors (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and Android.

H.265 / HEVC seems like a good choice too, but encoding with `x265`, for example, is currently still very slow compared to `x264`, the most popular open-source H.264 encoder.

Comment: Spot on answer, sorry it took so long to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

WebM and mp4 are only containers, not the actual encoders being used. Typically webm will be vp8 or vp9, and mp4 will most of the time be h264. You can change containers with a stream copy (ffmpeg command: -vcodec copy) but you can't change encoder type without encoding the entire stream. When you run a copy command, you also cannot resize the video, or change the bitrate. Copy is exactly how it sounds, you are copying the underlying frames exactly and wrapping them in a different container.

I will question why you want to encode to webm. Both ios and android will play (most all) mp4 videos without issue. If you want to enforce a certain format type, then you could check if the incoming video and try to enforce certain standards (ex. h264 baseline video and aac audio, no larger than 1080p). If an incoming stream does not conform to this standard, encode the video, specifying encoder, bitrate, and size. If it does fit within your standards, just run -vcodec copy -acodec copy. It looks like your specific library would be .audioCodec('copy') .videoCodec('copy').

Answer (score 1):

Thats easy, you just go for the same that the big vendors like youtube do, which is currently mp4/h.264/aac

As you target Android or better "any" OS or device, to get out the max. you have additionally to take care about the detailed settings of the codecs. Hardware decoders that are built in to devices tend to be pretty picky about what they want to decode.

Youtube defines the video codec settings this way

**for the h264:**

- Progressive scan (no interlacing)
- High Profile
- 2 consecutive B frames
- Closed GOP. GOP of half the frame rate.
- CABAC
- Variable bitrate. No bitrate limit required, though we offer recommended bit rates below for reference
- Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0

The only thing i can add: actually you should care about the bitrate, if you go too high (e.g. more than 15MBit/s for Full-HD video), hardware decoders might cause troubles.

**For the AAC:**

- Channels: Stereo or Stereo + 5.1
- Sample rate 96khz or 48khz

**Container: MP4**

- No Edit Lists (or the video might not get processed correctly)
- moov atom at the front of the file (Fast Start)

Furthermore, h264 is definitely the codec that has been worked on most which is why it can be encoded much faster than VP8/9 and co. So in my opinion there is no good reason (besides "ethic" ones) to go for h264 ONLY - not to mention that "x264" is even faster than h264 and should guarantee the same compatibility

**Conclusio:**

> Can anyone point out a code smell here regarding performance of this
>   operation? Is this code doing a lot more than it should to achieve
>   cross platform compatibility between IOS and Android?

Unfortunately no, it all depends on what kind of videos you get as input. Your code does definitely not too much, but far to less in terms of "try to save computing time". You could check if the input video matches all the listed parameters before you send it to encoding but to be honest, from experience most compatible results you will get is when you re-encode all your inputs to the settings above.